# Does Confluent Schema Registry keep track of the producers to various Kafka topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to plot an overall topology for my Kafka cluster (i.e., producers-->topics-->consumers).

For the mapping from topics to consumers, I'm able to obtain it using the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` script.

However, for the mapping from producers to topics, I understand there is no equivalent script in vanilla Kafka.

**Question**:
Does the Schema Registry allow us to associate metadata with producers and/or topics or otherwise create a mapping of all producers producing to a particular topic?

Answer (score 0):

Schema Registry has no such functionality

Closest I've seen to something like this, is using Distributed Tracing (Brave library) or Cloudera's SMM tool, which requires authorized Kafka clients so it can trace requests and Producer client.id to topics, then consumer instances to groups

There's also the [Stream Registry project](https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/stream-registry)
which I helped with the initial version for the vision of managing client state/discovery, but I think it took different direction and the documentation is not maintained